# How to redirect a URL from "example.com/search/.../?folder=something" to "example.com/something/search/.../"

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

How to redirect a URI from `example.com/search/.../?folder=something` to `example.com/something/search/.../`?

Is there a htaccess rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this rule as your first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^?]+)\?folder=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+?)/?$ /$2/?folder=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. unfortunately no luck. I already have a `RewriteRule ^(something|anything)/(.*) $2?folder=$1 [L,QSA,NC]` rule in the htaccess file. any more comments is appreciated.

Comment: Fixed a mistake, try again please.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, worked fine. again I appreciate you. cheers